# Polling over thousands of TCP sockets

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, threadpool

I need to connect to thousands of clients over TCP on a proprietary protocol to acquire data cyclically. I need to write a .NET server application in C#.

The first attempt was to create for each tcp socket an own thread, which works but needs a lot of cpu usage.

I found out that it would be a better idea to use the .NET threadpool instead. As far as I understand (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) I could use timers in order to get each socket acquire the data cyclically in a given period (like 1 sec). This does not work for me because the sockets time out once the connection was openende because there are a lot of more sockets which have to be opened before it's the open sockets turn again.

Another try was using asynchronous callbacks. This would work for me but I don't know how to get the sockets acquire data cyclically???

Comment: The words "thousands" and "threads" don't go hand-in-hand. Try to see if you can use the `await` keyword for continuations, this will allow you to write code against blocking ports without the code actually blocking very often. This is sort of the principle behind Erlang and Stackless Python - two languages built specifically for networking concurrency.

Comment: Why must you cycle thru the clients to acquire data?  it would be simpler (though that is relative) to just keep an async read posted on each socket and process data as they arrive.  If you really need cyclic reads you could postpone repost of an async read until all other sockets have been served.

Comment: Use asynchronous callbacks. You don't want do anything cyclically, so just forget that. It's a bad idea and makes no sense. You want to process the callbacks as they occur. You don't need timers either, unless there are specific things you need to time.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: The OP didn't specify .Net 4.5, so it's unlikely `await` would be an option.

Comment: @Gabe True, but that wasn't really the point of the comment.  And the OP didn't specify any .NET version with any of the new parallel stuff in it ;-)

Comment: I need to request the data cyclically. One request results in one answer. Establishing a connection takes some time, too. I'm using .NET 4. However, the await keywork could be an option for .NET 4.5. @ Steve: What do you mean by saying "keep an async read posted"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Socket's [high performance API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx) which allows simultaneously receiving data on a very large number of sockets, without using one thread per socket. At the bottom of the article there's a link to a complete sample. There's also a sample in the MSDN article for the [SocketAsyncEventArgs class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx).

Comment: The Socket's high performance API seems to be able to handle a lot of incoming connections. I need to open these connections instead. Is it possible to use the Socket's high performance API for this purpose as well?

Comment: Yes, create and open one socket per client, then use [`Socket.ReceiveAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why not populate a queue with the addresses you need to poll and have your thread pool take items off the queue to process?

Once you are done with an item push it to the back of the queue.

Comment: For one thing, if you have a lot of inactive connections, you'll waste a lot of time checking them for no reason.

Comment: I think this would take too much time for thousands of connections. I need updates from all sockets every second if possible.