# C# TCP/IP not working properly

Tags: c#, tcp, communication

I am working on a windows service that should collect all incoming TCP/IP streams with this class. It gets started from the services OnStart() void.

However I have encountered that when messages come in from a **second sender**, the whole communication stops working. The service then does not react to a single connection until you restart it.

```
public class TCPIP
{

    public static Receiver rc = new Receiver();

    public class Receiver
    {

        public delegate void ReceivedEventHandler(string ReceivedText, string Sender);

        public event ReceivedEventHandler Received;

        public void Start()
        {

            System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(internals);
            th.Start();
        }

        private void internals()
        {

            TcpListener _listener = new TcpListener(1994);
            _listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {

                TcpClient rcclient = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rcclient.GetStream());

                string msg = "";

                while (reader.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    msg += Convert.ToChar(reader.Read()).ToString();
                }

                Received(msg, rcclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))[0]);

                // Cleanup
                rcclient.Close();
                reader.Close();

            }

        }
```

Could anybody help me out improving this class to answer connections from **multiple endpoints**, and to not be occupied after one?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What happens when you trace it

Comment: _"all incoming TCP/IP messages"_ - TCP deals in streams, not messages. Anyway if you want to capture all packets, you want a network filter driver, which you can't do in C#.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah I'm only talking one port, but for multiple endpoints.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a thread when you accept some connection, so if it's blocked will not afect the main program.

Btw you can try [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent blocking calls.

Comment: How we can manage huge amount of connections? Using stacks of connections to be processed?
PD: I just proposed one simple solution, not the best.

Comment: You proposed a solution that might work for a few days, then blow up spectacularly in any real-life scenario. That's not a solution and doesn't help anyone. See for example [Polling over thousands of TCP sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300428/polling-over-thousands-of-tcp-sockets).

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you, to express myself a bit more clearly, I'd like to have the service accept connections from more than one endpoint. It's all the same TCP port. Have you got an idea?